# Problema con str.contains, pandas y un bucle if

Tags: python, string, pandas, condiciones

Tengo un problema con un bucle y por más que lo intento no consigo dar con la solución. He buscado por internet también, y nada. Os comento.

Voy a simplificar el problema inventándome un df. El df tiene 2 columnas: tipo_comida y producto.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
tipo_comida = ["fruta","fruta","fruta","verdura","fruta","carne","verdura","carne"],
producto = ["manzana 15gr", "pera grande", "manzana pequeña","espinacas","sandía","pollo","alcachofa","ternera"]))
```

Bien. La columna "tipo_comida" no tiene ningún problema, pero en la columna "producto" hay un verdadero caos. Por ejemplo, manzana aparece de varias formas distintas, y pera tiene el adjetivo "grande".

¿Qué estoy intentando? Quiero, en primer lugar, filtrar por la columna "tipo_comida" las filas que contengan "fruta" y, para cada una, preguntar si la cadena contiene "manzana", "pera" o "sandía", ignorando el resto de palabras que puedan contener. Si contiene "manzana", en otra columna ("producto_arreglado") quiero que se escriba solo "manzana".

¿Cómo lo he intentado?

```
def correccion_producto(q):
    if q["tipo_comida"]=="fruta":
        if q["producto"].str.contains("manzana"):
            return ("manzana")
    else:
        pass
df["producto_arreglado"] = df.apply(correccion_producto, axis=1)
```

Esto, pero luego haciendo otro elif en el que el str.contains fuese "pera", y otro con "sandía". Y luego, lo propio con *if q["tipo_comida"] == "verdura"*

Pero solo con el código que he puesto tengo el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o qué me estoy dejando?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: No, el error que aparece ahora es: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: `if "manzana" in q["producto"]:`

Comment: Vale, el bucle funciona, pero me salta otro error. Por lo visto hay algun float (algunos nombres de productos tienen nombres) y no puedo iterar: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: Estas aplicando `correccion_producto` a todas las columnas, deberías hacerlo solo en aquella que te interesa

Comment: Ignoro por completo dónde tengo que indicarlo, @PatricioMoracho. El problema es que involucro 2 columnas distintas (tipo_comida y producto). Me interesan ambas, según creo, pero no sé dónde indicarlo.

Comment: Posiblemente algo así: `df[, ['col1', 'col2']].apply(correccion_producto, axis=1)`

Comment: Nada, me sigue apareciendo esto: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable. Tengo esto: 

df[["tipo_comida","producto"]].apply(correccion_producto, axis=1)

En el df original hay más columnas, pero no creo que esto influya en tanto que estamos especificando a qué columnas queremos involucrar, ¿no? Debo decir que si corro este código con el ejemplo que he puesto de verduras va bien.

Comment: Vale, acabo de hacer algunos cambios. En el df de ejemplo, he puesto un 4. Es un número entero, no una cadena. Y si corro el código, entonces me sale el mismo error: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable. En el df original me aparece float en lugar de int, pero habrá de todo.

Comment: Puedes convertir todos los datos de la columna a cadena con `df.producto.astype(str)`.

Comment: Vale, perfecto, ahora funciona todo bien. Sigo sin entender la razón por la que no podía iterar sin cambiar el tipo de dato, pero el código se ejecuta correctamente ahora. Indagaré más en ello para comprender lo sucedido. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es primero convertir los datos de las columnas que deseas a `string` al inicio de tu función (Cambié uno de los valores de manzana por un entero)

Ejemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    tipo_comida = ["fruta","fruta","fruta","verdura","fruta","carne","verdura","carne"],
    producto = ["manzana 15gr", "pera grande", 14,"espinacas","sandía","pollo","alcachofa","ternera"]))

def correccion_producto(q):
    comida = str(q['tipo_comida'])
    producto = str(q['producto'])
    if comida == "fruta":
        if 'manzana' in producto:
            return ("manzana")
        elif 'pera' in producto:
            return ("pera")
    else:
        pass
df["producto_arreglado"] = df.apply(correccion_producto, axis=1)
```

El `df` resultante es:

```
    tipo_comida producto
0   fruta       manzana 15gr
1   fruta       pera grande
2   fruta       14
3   verdura     espinacas
4   fruta       sandía
5   carne       pollo
6   verdura     alcachofa
7   carne       ternera
```

Comment: Perfecto, funciona. Ignoro la razón por la que hay que cambiar el tipo de dato antes de poder iterar, pero el código funciona. Indagaré más sobre lo que ha sucedido. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay que cambiar el tipo de dato obligatoriamente, lo puedes hacer sin la conversión pero en tu caso mencionaste que algunas veces no hay texto sino valores numéricos, en ese caso si tienes que cambiar primero a `string`. Si tus columnas tuvieran tipo de valor constante podrías hacerlo sin conversión